# How to deal with time-based conditions in an event-driven architecture?

Tags: event-programming, apache-kafka

The company I work for has a ticketing platform. The backend system consists of a few applications talking to each other via HTTP and through events in Kafka. A ticket has a `sell_start_date` field indicating when it can start being sold. We have to develop an application exposes available tickets as a HTTP service. For performance reasons, we have to keep the tickets in memory. There is a topic in Kafka containing ticket CRUD information. So when a ticket is created in the backoffice, an event is published to this topic.

Our new application could consume all of these events to populate its in-memory cache. The problem is that we don't want to store tickets with `sell_start_date` far in the future. But if, when consuming an event, we discard it based on this, we'll lose it as it won't be published again. Periodically reprocessing the topic is not an option because the topic's retention time is 7 days and the tickets might be created much earlier.

The only option that we can think of is having job that, instead of reading from Kafka, periodically reads from the DB where we keep all tickets. This creates some other complications that we'd like to avoid. It'd be great if we could somehow leverage the event-driven architecture to also include time-based events, not having to use periodic jobs.

This, having time-based events/conditions, seems like a common problem. How are people solving it?

Comment: In general, the database is a good place to store things that you don't need in memory right now or in the immediate future, so many people will use a database. It is also safer against service interruptions. The application that exposes available tickets just need some way of retrieving tickets from database when they're up for sale. This can be triggered through an internal polling process or some external process that generates events when certain times are reached. Maybe it's easier to name and solve the complications that you want to avoid?

Comment: Do you have timed events?

Comment: @candied_orange At a conceptual level, we have timed events: those given by the tickets' `sell_start_date`. But I don't know how to implement those other than by periodically polling the DB.